# How can I check if an array contains null values inside typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an array that might include `null` or `undefined` values

```
const uncertainObjectIds = ['5fc657037ed3e03d506e1e25', null, '5fc657037ed3e03d506e1e26', undefined]
```

If `uncertainObjectIds` does include any null or undefined values I will throw an error. However, if it does not and I am sure that the array is full of defined values and no undefined values I wanna use it.

```
  const doNullValuesExistInsideObjectIds = uncertainObjectIds.some(
    (objectIdOrNull) => !objectIdOrNull,
  );

  if (doNullValuesExistInsideObjectIds) {
    throw new UserInputError(
      'All Users must have ObjectIds',
    );
  }

const usersCollection = await getCollection('users');
  const originalUsers = await usersCollection.find({
    _id: { $in: uncertainObjectIds },
  });
```

but TypesSript gives me an error.

```
Type '(ObjectId | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'ObjectId[]'
```

What is the best way to handle this use case inside TypeScript?

Comment: Is your array an array of strings? Why are there no quotes?

Comment: They are an array of MongoDB ObjectIds, but I will add the quotes.

Comment: `uncertainObjectIds.filter(f => !!f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to accomplish this:

```
function nonNull<T>(arr: (T | null | undefined)[]): arr is T[] {
    return arr.every(v => v !== null && v !== undefined);
}

const mixed = [1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, undefined, 6];

// uncommenting this line will error due to having null values
// const x: number[] = mixed;

// apply the type guard
if (!nonNull(mixed)) {
    throw new Error("Cannot have null values.");
}

// no longer has null values
const y: number[] = mixed;
```